# Can I print editable text to a console?

Tags: linux, perl

I want to print to console text that the user can edit. It is possible?

My program get some values from the user and in one place ask a value that can be the sum of previous input or a part or nothing.

Linux machine.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [Term::UI](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/UI.html) ?

Comment: If you want to get really fancy you can try Curses http://www.bribes.org/perl/CursesWidgetsDemo.png

Comment: both great tools. thx both